# Duplicate / Same "mappedBy" value within a single entity with multiple OneToOne / one-to-one relations

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Can someone give me a hand with mapping this scenario? I tried adding a Salary table and reference to the Instructor just to scratch my curiosity, but only the Details table populates the instructor_id column. The Salary table shows null as the instructor_id, so it doesn't have a relation to the Instructor. How do I link both the details and the salary to the instructor using OneToOne relations? Here is what I tried. An explanation with the solution would be helpful as well. Thanks in advance.

```
@Entity(name = "instructor")
@Table(name = "instructor")
public class Instructor {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy= "instructor", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Details details;
    
    @OneToOne(mappedBy= "instructor", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Salary salary;
}

@Entity(name = "details")
@Table(name = "details")
public class Details {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    @OneToOne
    private Instructor instructor;
}

@Entity(name = "salary")
@Table(name = "salary")
public class Salary {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    @OneToOne
    private Instructor instructor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this was happening because i wasnt setting the instructor in the salary object. i was setting it in the details object.

```
details.setInstructor(instructor);
salary.setInstructor(instructor);   <<<< the solution
```